# Try to use a selectSinglenode with a soap envelope

Tags: c#, xml

I have this xml :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <Infolog xmlns="http://schemascom/2010/01/datacontracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Entries/>
        </Infolog>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <Response xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
            <result xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dynamics.AX.Application" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:ExtXLSContract>
                    <a:Client>false</a:Client>
                    <a:Code/>
                    <a:Account>false</a:Account>
                    <a:Environement>AxGH</a:Environement>
                    <a:Filiale/>
                    <a:Nom/>
                </a:ExtXLSContract>
            </result>
        </Response>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I want to select the node `<a:Environement>`.

When I use a Xpath tester on a web, I tried:

```
//s:Envelope/s:body/Response/result/ExtXLSContract/a:Environement
```

And I get my data.

But when I do:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dynamics.AX.Application");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
                
var value = doc.SelectSingleNode("//s:Envelope/s:body/Response/result/ExtXLSContract/a:Environement", nsmgr);
```

`value` is always null - why?

Comment: `Response` and `result` nodes have default namespace `http://tempuri.org`. You must specify it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Apply below changes:

- Change `s:body` to `s:Body`
- `Response` and `result` must be have a prefix linked to the `http://tempuri.org` xml namespace.  You'll need to register that namespace with the `NamespaceManager`,
  e.g.: `nsmgr.AddNamespace("t", "http://tempuri.org");`
- `ExtXLSContract` must have the `a` prefix you already defined.

The XPATH statement then will look like

```
//s:Envelope/s:Body/t:Response/t:result/a:ExtXLSContract/a:Environement
```

---

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("t", "http://tempuri.org");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dynamics.AX.Application");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");


var value = doc.SelectSingleNode("//s:Envelope/s:Body/t:Response/t:result/a:ExtXLSContract/a:Environement", nsmgr);
```